# Importing package from parallel or higher order directory in Python 3.6+

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

My python project is structured as follows [image]

In order to user logr.py of comUtil package from dataPreparation package one has to tweak its sys path as follows

`import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import comUtil.logr as logg`

Now the question is

1. Is this an accepted practice and are there any drawbacks for such usage ?
2. What are other alternatives and possibly better ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to set the path till `dataIngestionTool`. Because this is your project's root directory.
And then import files as:

```
from dataIngestionTool.comUtil.logr import *
```

or

```
from dataIngestionTool.comUtil import logr
```

Comment: This doesn't work and throws an error `from DataIngestionTool.dataIngestionTool.comUtil import logr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DataIngestionTool'
`

Comment: @sanjeevkumar It is because there is no __init__.py file in DataIngestionTool folder. You can either check the updated ans or create a __init__.py file.

Comment: Well there are three init.py files , if you look at the picture ... and the reason why that is happening is Python pics the path of the current folder in which the code is getting executed and searches for packages down the hierarchy. Hence you are suppose to add parent folder path to sys path.

Answer (score 0):

1. `sys.path.append('../')` permanently appends this path to the list. Now, if you are going to `import a_random_module` for example in `driver.py`, the package manager will also start looking for `a_random_module` in the parent directory of `driver.py`.
2. I would suggest something like this to add a certain path to sys:

   ```
   import sys                                                            
   import os                                                             
   def append_specific_dir_to_sys_path():                                 
       current_dir = os.getcwd()
       parent_dir = current_dir.split('/')[:-1]                              
       import_dir = '/'.join(parent_dir) + '/comUtil/'                       
       sys.path.append(import_dir)        
   append_specific_dir_to_sys_path()
   ```